# How do you solve the Schrödinger equation with a position space delta function potential in momentum space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I am solving the Schrodinger equation in position space with an attractive delta function potential energy,
$$
-\frac{h^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi(x)-\lambda \delta(x) \psi(x)=E \psi(x),
$$
for a bound state. I need to solve for E, using fourier transform. I took the fourier transform of the whole equation and ended up with,
$$
-\frac{h^2}{2m} (ik)^2\phi(k)-\lambda \delta(k) \phi(k)=E\phi(k).
$$
After using, 
$$
\delta(k) =1 \text{ or } 2\pi
$$ 
I don't get the required energy for this attractive potential, I would be glad if anyone could help? As I remember the energy expression should be 
$$
E=-\frac{m\lambda^2}{2h^2}.
$$

Comment: To clarify: do you just want to solve the delta function potential, or are you insistent on solving it using the Fourier transform?

Comment: I want to find the value of E using fourier transform.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the position space SE with potential $-\lambda \delta(x)$. Define the Fourier transform as:
$$\tilde \psi(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int dx \,\,e^{-ikx/\hbar}\psi(x)$$
The Fourier transform of the product is given by:
$$\mathcal{F}[\delta(x)\psi(x)](k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int dx \,\,e^{-ikx/\hbar}\delta(x)\psi(x)=\frac{\psi(0)}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$$
The momentum space SE therefore gives:
$$\tilde \psi(k)= \frac{\lambda\psi(0)}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\frac{1}{(k^2/2m-E)}$$
Inverting the transform:
$$\psi(x)= \frac{\lambda\psi(0)}{2\pi\hbar}\int dk \,\frac{e^{ikx/\hbar}}{k^2/2m-E}=\frac{m\lambda\psi(0)}{\hbar\sqrt{-2mE}}\exp{\left(-\frac{\sqrt{-2mE}}{\hbar}|x|\right)}$$
where the result of the integral in the second step is standard and can be obtained from tables of Fourier transforms. Setting $x=0$, we obtain $E$ in terms of $\lambda$:
$$E=-\frac{m\lambda^2}{2\hbar^2}$$